# Post Method and Redirect With Some Values Without Form C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, post

```
<form action="https://somewebsiteaddrest" method="post">
   <input name="Var1"  type="hidden" value="Variable 1 value" />
   <input name="Var2"  type="hidden" value="Variable 2 value" />
   <input name="Var3"  type="hidden" value="Variable 3 value" />
   <input name="Var4"  type="hidden" value="Variable 4 value" />
   <input name="Var5"  type="hidden" value="Variable 6 value" />
   <input type="submit" value="Go now" />
</form>
```

I want to create equal post method and redirection (in C#) without using this form and **javascript**  `frm.submit()`;

I've a C# code snippet which I expect to do the stuff.

```
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    string postData = "What to write here? here should be variable i guess.";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();


string postData
```

what to write in postData to get the same effect as it will be by using `form` and `form.submit()`? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The post data should be URL-encoded form data, i.e. key=value pairs separated by `&` characters. Use the [`UrlEncode` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) to encode the values:

```
string postData =
  "Var1=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Variable 1 value")+
  "&Var2=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Variable 2 value")+
  "&Var3=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Variable 3 value")+
  "&Var4=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Variable 4 value")+
  "&Var5=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Variable 6 value");
```

Comment: Thanks. Will it have the same effect as submitting form?

Answer (score 0):

PostData="Var1=xxx&Var2=yyyy...."

Answer (score 0):

[POST requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) provide a body that uses URL encoding to send the data.

You can use [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) to encode your data.

So for example you can have code like this:

```
string ToQueryString(IEnumerable data)
{
    return string.Join("&", data.Select(d => HttpUtility.UrlEncode(d.ToString())));
}
```